# ant design change select background color when disabled

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro, antdv, ant-design-vue

I am trying to change the background color of a select drop down when disabled.

I was testing with: `.ant-select-disabled .ant-select-selection{background-color: red}` with no luck.
For example, on regular inputs I got it to work: `.ant-input:disabled{background-color: red}`

This is for VueJS

Comment: Selectors are correct. Try !important, may be you have styles which override.

Comment: didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use styles in the Select drop down

```
<Select
   style={
     backgroundColor: "red",
   }
>
        .....
              
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this; this works for me.

```
.ant-select-selection-item{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dropdownStyle` prop on Select to style it.